# Run One instance of Discord bot per server, So bot doesn't turn on on every server

Tags: discord.js

So my code activates a listener which will then just simply return the message to the user. However, once the listener is activated, it will be GLOBALLY activated, so all servers with this bot will be affected. How can i create one instance of the bot per server.

Comment: Are you trying to make a specific message relay to a user? E.g, if someone says says "something", it will send a message to that user's DMs?

Comment: No, it can work in the dm's but its designed to work in the servers. However, enabling in one server will enable in all, because my bot is only one instance running everywhere

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run multiple instances of a bot would be to copy the bot's code and use it in several other bots. You'd need to create several bot applications/users from the developers page and generate tokens for each bot.

It's a bit sketchy and **not recommended** so I'd be careful with what you're trying to achieve here.